# Get echo from php and open it in inappbrowser ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Im sending a string to my php file which creates an encoded string from it and gives an echo back. I try to catch the encoded echo and open the echo in my inapp browser but it dont work. Wheres my failure?

My JS Code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
              $("#paybutton").click(function() {
                                    var params = "projectpaymentoption=1197&id=",
                                    usernamepay = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
                                    paymenturl = params + usernamepay;

                                    $.ajax({
                                           type: 'POST',
                                           url: 'http://www.blabla.com/encode.php',
                                           data: $.param({"paymenturl": paymenturl}),
                                           success: function(output) {


                                           window.open('output','_blank','location=no','closebuttoncaption=Zurück');






                                           console.log(result);
                                           }
                                           });
                                    });
              });
```

and heres my encode php:

```
   <?php

print_r($_POST); // see full contents of the POST
$user = $_POST['paymenturl'];
print PHP_EOL . $user . PHP_EOL; // see full contents of the $user var
$password = "blaaa"; 
$salt = "blaaa";

function encode($password,$decrypted,$salt){    
$key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);    
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,  
MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);   
if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) {  
throw new Exception("Encoding failed!");  
}  
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,   
$decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)); 
return urlencode($iv_base64 . $encrypted);  }

$en = encode($password,$user,$salt);
$output = "http://blablabla.com/Payments/Connect/1197/DE?o={$en}";
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: You said "it dont work"; could you explain more about the exact problem?
Also, please fix the indentation in both code sections (e.g. to 4 spaces per tab) - the js section has too much indentation and the php has none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing all the *print* and *print_r* in your **php**, leaving only final *echo*, so that your ajax call would receive only needed data.
Also, encode your output

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: But when i use json_encode it will put in my url forward slashes and the url doesent work anymore. And JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES will not work. Then i get no response.

Comment: @mav Happy to help, if you decide to encode your output data, you can easily decode it in js using jQuery.parseJSON. Also you can mark my answer as accepted if it helped solve your issue.

Comment: what if i am receiving a php page that is dynamically generated with include statements..the ajax value returned shows the full page but unable to display it in inappbrowser